# How to show and hide a success animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

Currently, I'm coding a math game with random questions that the user may input the correct answer.

I want to display a short Lottie (0.5 seconds) when the user insert the answer correctly. It must appear and quickly hide to continue with the questions.

Have you got any idea?

I want to create something like this.

[image]

I tried using `showDialog`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy implementation of what you want using a Stack with 3 children:

1. a button (replace this with your game UI)
2. an overlay that is hidden by default
3. a Center widget with a Container (replace this with the Lottie)

The function showLottie() will switch the lottieIsVisible to true, wait 2 seconds and set it back to false.

Heres the code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool lottieIsVisible = false;

  showLottie() {
    setState(() {
      lottieIsVisible = true;
    });
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        lottieIsVisible = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Game UI goes here
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: showLottie,
              child: Text(
                'Show Lottie',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          lottieIsVisible
          // The overlay
              ? Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                )
              : Container(),
          lottieIsVisible
          // The Lottie
              ? Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Lottie goes her',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot when lottieIsVisible = true]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! Here I found a solution that I want to share.
We can make this also using the widget Timer. It works!

Here is the code:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (BuildContext builderContext) {
    _timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 750), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });

    return Center(
      child:  Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        width: 250,
        child: Lottie.asset(
          'assets/lotties/ticLottie.json',
          fit: BoxFit.contain
        ),
      )
  );
  }
).then((val){
  if (_timer.isActive) {
    _timer.cancel();
  }
});
```